# Using boost multiprecision with RcppEigen

Tags: r, boost, eigen, rcpp, armadillo

I have written a library using RcppArmadillo. The problem I have is that for some parameters, the arma::solve function does not give me the exact solution, since the "A" matrix has an rcond close to 0. If arma::solve could solve the linear equation exactly, that would not be a problem. But it gives me an approximate solution, which is not good enough for me.

Then, I have thought in using RcppEigen, and use boost multiprecision variables. If I understand correctly Eigen, the Eigen solver will give me a solution in multiprecision, and it is quite likely this solution will be good enough for me (even with a float128).

But when I try to implement this plan, I have an error, and I do not know what to do. For example, the following works:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppEigen.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdint>
#include <boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/eigen.hpp>

// Correctly setup the build environment 
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::multiprecision;
using Eigen::Map;
using Eigen::MatrixXd;                  // variable size matrix, double precision
using Eigen::VectorXd;
using Eigen::Matrix;
using Eigen::Dynamic;
namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;


    // [[Rcpp::export]]
    Eigen::MatrixXd onesfgh_LPPLS_RcppEigen(int t2, int t1, double tc, double m, double w) {
      //Definitions & pre-computations:
      unsigned int tdim;
      double ttc, powttc, wlog, sinwlog, coswlog;
      tdim = t2 - t1 + 1;
      ttc = tc - t1 + 1;
      Eigen::MatrixXd output(tdim, 4); //first dimension is time, second is onesfgh
      //Main calculations:
      for (unsigned int i = 0; i < tdim; i++) {
        output(i, 0) = 1.0;
        ttc--;
        powttc = pow(ttc, m);
        wlog = w * log(ttc);
        sinwlog = sin(wlog);
        coswlog = cos(wlog);
        //sincos(wlog, &sinwlog, &coswlog);
        output(i, 1) = powttc;
        output(i, 2) = coswlog * powttc;
        output(i, 3) = sinwlog * powttc;
      }
      return output;
    }
```

But:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Eigen::Matrix<boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::float128, boost::multiprecision::et_off>, Eigen::Dynamic, 4> onesfgh_LPPLS_RcppEigen(int t2, int t1, double tc, double m, double w) {
  //Definitions & pre-computations:
  unsigned int tdim;
  boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::float128, boost::multiprecision::et_off> tc128(tc), m128(m), w128(w);
  boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::float128, boost::multiprecision::et_off> ttc, powttc, wlog, sinwlog, coswlog;
  boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::float128, boost::multiprecision::et_off> t1128(double(t1));
  tdim = t2 - t1 + 1;
  ttc = tc128 - t1128 + 1.0;
  Eigen::Matrix<boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::float128, boost::multiprecision::et_off>, Eigen::Dynamic, 4> output(tdim, 4); //first dimension is time, second is onesfgh
  //Main calculations:
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < tdim; i++) {
    output(i, 0) = 1.0;
    ttc--;
    powttc = boost::multiprecision::pow(ttc, m128);
    wlog = w128 * boost::multiprecision::log(ttc);
    sinwlog = boost::multiprecision::sin(wlog);
    coswlog = boost::multiprecision::cos(wlog);
    //sincos(wlog, &sinwlog, &coswlog);
    output(i, 1) = powttc;
    output(i, 2) = coswlog * powttc;
    output(i, 3) = sinwlog * powttc;
  }
  return output;
}
```

it does not work. I get the error message:

```
RcppExports.cpp:11:15: error: 'boost' was not declared in this scope
```

In particular, I have tried the advice given in https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/high_precision/using_test.html but without using a typedef, since in another post, Dirk Eddelbuettel suggests typedefs are not easy to deal with (and they should be place in another .h file).

Is there any suggestion how to proceed?

**EDIT:**

I have modified the function, by not exporting. Now the code is:

```
  #include <RcppArmadillo.h>
    #include <RcppEigen.h>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <cstdint>
    #include <boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp>
    #include <boost/multiprecision/eigen.hpp>

    // Correctly setup the build environment 
    // [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
    // [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
    // [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
    using namespace Rcpp;
    using namespace arma;
    using namespace Eigen;
    using namespace boost;
    using namespace boost::multiprecision;
    using Eigen::Map;
    using Eigen::MatrixXd;                  
    using Eigen::VectorXd;
    using Eigen::Matrix;
    using Eigen::Dynamic;
    namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;

    Eigen::Matrix<mp::float128, Eigen::Dynamic, 4> onesfgh_LPPLS_RcppEigen(int `t2, int t1, double tc, double m, double w) {`
      //Definitions & pre-computations:
      unsigned int tdim;
      mp::float128 tc128(tc), m128(m), w128(w);
      mp::float128 ttc, powttc, wlog, sinwlog, coswlog;
      mp::float128 t1128(double(t1));
      tdim = t2 - t1 + 1;
      ttc = tc128 - t1128 + 1.0;
      Eigen::Matrix<mp::float128, Eigen::Dynamic, 4> output(tdim, 4); 
      //Main calculations:
      for (unsigned int i = 0; i < tdim; i++) {
        output(i, 0) = 1.0;
        ttc--;
        powttc = mp::pow(ttc, m128);
        wlog = w128 * mp::log(ttc);
        sinwlog = mp::sin(wlog);
        coswlog = mp::cos(wlog);
        //sincos(wlog, &sinwlog, &coswlog);
        output(i, 1) = powttc;
        output(i, 2) = coswlog * powttc;
        output(i, 3) = sinwlog * powttc;
      }
      return output;
    }
```

And now I get the following error message:

```
babel_RcppArmadillo.cpp:6:42: fatal error: boost/multiprecision/eigen.hpp: 
No such file or directory
#include <boost/multiprecision/eigen.hpp>                                          
compilation terminated.
```

Which is odd, since I assume that BH includes the subfolders of boost.

Comment: do you include the `BH` package?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Stéphane Laurent. I have BH installed in my system. I have BH in "Imports:" and "LinkingTo:" in my DESCRIPTION file. Should I do anything else, in addition to what I have done?

Comment: Weird, that looks correct. When I used boost, I also included the line `// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]` at the top of the `cpp` file, but I think this line is useless actually.

Comment: Oh sorry, I've just seen you also have included this line.

Comment: In fact, I have googled, and I have not found much information about the interaction of RcppEigen and boost, especially regarding multiprecision. I believe that inversion of matrices tends to be a relevant subject for many people. Might I ask if anybody more knowledgeable than me could direct me to a "trivial" example where RcppEigen, boost multiprecision (and ideally an Eigen solver) work together? I would highly appreciate that. I know that time is limited for everybody.

Comment: I don't know. FYI, `float128` is better but slower than `long double`. I would try `long double` before trying `float128`.

Comment: Ah wait your function returns a `Matrix<float128>` and you export it. I think this is not possible. There's no equivalent of `float128` in R. Have you tried to return a `Matrix<double>` instead, by casting?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about using a long double. I even think that the precision of long double would be enough for me. But let me ask you: are you thinking in using long double in Eigen? Or do you think that a long double could in fact used in say Armadillo, and get a better numerical solution in the Armadillo solver? I assume that last question has a "No" answer, but I was just wondering about it. Thank you!

Comment: I have never used `armadillo`. I have tried `long double` in `Eigen` and it works  fine (but you can't export a function returning a `Matrix<long double>`).

Comment: Ah. So, I have two options: either export the function, and then I have to cast to double, or I do not export the function, and then I can continue returning a `Matrix<float128>`, which can be used as an argument in another function, right?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: Are you sure your boost version is up-to-date? `boost/multiprecision/eigen.hpp` seems to have been included only recently.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. BH is version 1.66.0-1, so I think then it is updated. But how can I know in an easy way if boost itself is up-to-date? For example, if I go to gmp.hpp, I see the modified day is yesterday.

Comment: I am little confused by this long question.  Are you assuming that Eigen changes its own numeric precision just by you also using a multiprecision library?

Comment: Yes, I was assuming that. Otherwise, what is the reason to allow Eigen to use multiprecision variables? For example, in https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/eigen.html it is stated "The relative error is: 2.63132e-34". Isn't this low relative error due to using multiprecision variables for the Eigen solver? Would this relate error be accomplished with doubles?

Comment: The point is that this particular header has been added in boost 1.68, while BH provides boost 1.66. So you have to install a more recent boost version independently.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, @RalfStubner. In simple terms, what should I do, to install boost 1.68 and make it work in R? Where should the folder be, and how should I call it? I assume the "// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]" has to be dropped.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Eigen supports [using custom scalar types](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_CustomScalar.html).

Comment: @chtz At the Eigen level, but he is doing this from R via Rcpp and RcppEigen, and that will magically adapt to new types.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Admittedly, I have no experience with R/Rcpp/RcppEigen ...

Comment: Ooops, missed an important *not* there:   R/Rcpp/RcppEigen will *not* magically adapt to new types.   It can be done (and we have documentation) but it is real work -- and I have the feeling OP wants something magic here.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I understand now your comment: any floating type which is not a double, must be casted into double to be used in R. Having said that and having now a better understanding, my questions holds. BTW, my experience is a long double does not need to be explicitly casted into double when exported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** This should be unnecessary by now, since the [BH package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BH/) includes the required header since January 2019.

---

The `boost/multiprecision/eigen.hpp` header was added in [version 1.68](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_68_0.html), while the [BH package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BH/) currently provides boost 1.66. You have to install an updated boost separately. The following should work but is untested:

1. Download boost 1.68 and unpack it into some suitable directory. On Linux and other Unix-like systems I would probably use `/usr/local/include`. Otherwise I would use any path without spaces in the name.
2. Do not depend on the BH package, i.e. remove `// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]` for `sourceCpp` et al. or `Imports: BH` for package use.
3. If boost was installed in a non-standard location in step 1., you have to tell the compiler to look there. This can be done with

   ```
   PKG_CPPFLAGS=-I<path-to-boost>
   ```

   either via `Sys.setenv` for `sourceCpp` et al. or within `src/Makevars(.win)` for package use.

Comment: I have done what you kindly suggested. I have also updated gcc to 8.1.0 in Rtools, since a simple sourceCpp was not working with 4.* in Rtools (but I can create Rcpp packages w/o problems). But now I get the following error message in the compilation: `c:/rtools/mingw_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgfortran
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status` I guess that I need to set some kind of flag for -lgfortran in the package and / or I need to install a new version of gfortran. Are there any recommendations?

Comment: @AnarcocapitalistaSocialdemocr Installing a matching `gfortran` might help. But I have no experience with using other compilers than the Rtools provided one on windows.

Comment: I have reinstalled Rtools (getting rid of gcc 8.1.0) and after following the steps of @RalfStubner, I have been able to successfully compile with the line `#include <boost/multiprecision/eigen.hpp>`. I cannot use sourceRcpp, but this is not a big thing. I will check if I can use eigen + boost now. Thank you.